# use multiple ip addresses to tcp check remote server's port

Tags: linux, linux-networking, telnet, nmap

Im trying to tcp connect yahoo's mail server on port 25 . I have 3 public ip addresses lets say:-

```
(all are allowed in SPF records)
99.99.99.99
77.77.77.77
88.88.88.88
```

How to telnet(or other checks) using particular ip addresses to yahoos mta
(check if all three of my ip addresses are allowed to send email to yahoo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nc -s 77.77.77.77 -vz mta5.am0.yahoodns.net 25
```

OR

```
telnet -b 77.77.77.77 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net 25
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page: *-s* sets the source IP address.

So you can do:

```
telnet -s 77.77.77.77 yahoo_mail_server 25
```

Comment: for centos 6.7 with telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64.  it has "-b"  switch instead of "-s"